# Invite friends to facebook application on android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I know there are many posts on that subject, still could'nt find a good reference for making this happen.

in Graph v2 of facebook, I try to create in my app a simple facebook dialog so that I will able to invite my friends to this app.
now I know it is possible, yet I had no luck in making this happen.

it is not a game, and no use in facebook canvas.
also I'm using parse technology, but already saw that except connecting to facebook they have no API for facebook.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Basically, if your App is a game with a Canvas implementation, use requests. If not, use the message or send dialog. In your case (Android App), that would be the message dialog.

Comment: can you parhaps direct me to the correct place where to read about it, all I find is sharing conent between users of the app and not getting all your friends and send them an invitation to download the app itself..

Comment: just follow the link in my answer. there are a lot of sub-links. although, what you describe sounds spammy. also, you said it´s not a game on canvas, so don´t use the invitation stuff. again, it´s all in the link in my answer.